# Installation Issues

Tags: 12.04, installation

Over the past few months I have been flitting back and forth between Ubuntu and Windows. However, in my most recent attempt to go back to Ubuntu due to its advantages to my course, no matter how I try and install it (CD/USB or just the Windows installer) it always freezes at the same point for the CD/USB or fails with the installer.

Below is a picture I took of it with my phone, hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have a bad copy on your CD or USB stick; if I were you I would find the .iso file for the Ubuntu you want and burn it to a CD, verifying it to make sure it is a good copy.  Then boot that up and try again.  I have done this many times, usually it works fine.